# Is there Movesense restart command?

Tags: movesense

Unit can be turned off with

```
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_MODE::ID, AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true),(uint8_t)1U);
```

Is there restart option? Perhaps in

```
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_MAX3000X_WAKEUP::ID,AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true), (uint8_t)1);
```

eplacing contact 1 with something else? I want to clean everything and reset sensor counters between long measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_MODE::ID, AsyncRequestOptions::ForceAsync, WB_RES::SystemMode::APPLICATION);
```

or ... (uint8_t) 5U

for trying to enter the same system mode again. Not sure if it works and can't confirm right now, but definitely worth trying!

Comment: Thank you. 5U worked  asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_MODE::ID, AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true),(uint8_t)5U);